# Android - Opening the email application?

Tags: android, email, android-activity, android-intent

I want to open the email application on my android app:
The following code crashes
Am I doing anything wrong? please provide code

```
Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND,Uri.fromParts("mailto", "testemail@gmail.com", null));
this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Answer (score 8):

Try This :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:"
            + "xyz@abc.com"
            + "?subject=" + "Feedback" + "&body=" + "");
    intent.setData(data);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Prefer to use constants if available like for intent.type `ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN`

Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.type = ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("emailId 1", "emailId 2"))
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject for email")
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Description for email")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Email"))
```

Java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"emailId 1", "emailId 2"});
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject for email");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Description for email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Email"));
```