# Hyperlink in android studio

Tags: android

There is a button "CONTACT ME". New activity opens when this button is clicked. I want to provide my 'linked in' page, 'quora' page, and 'gmail id' in that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Contrast to the three texview method you could also try it with a single textview
that has some text with   the clickable words in it.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("My Linkedin  page , quora page  ");

ClickableSpan span1 = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
   //  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse   ("https://your.link.com"));
   // yourActivity.startActivity(browserIntent);       
   }
};

ClickableSpan span2 = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        // do another thing
    }
};
```

Now set the clickable parts in the text like:-

```
ss.setSpan(span1, 3, 11, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(span2, 20, 24, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

by passing the starting index and last index of the clickable texts.

```
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thank-you for the code. But where should I provide the links. So sorry, but I was unable to comprehend your code.

Comment: you would need to write down  your  intent code for each url in their respective clickListeners

Comment: Yes its done.. Thank-you so much for taking interest in my question. But I have done it the other way. So sorry for that.. and thankyou once again. :)

Comment: good to know that it's done, hope you could apply the solution may be some other place.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, you may need to provide more info in the future for you questions.

If you just need to know how to open a link in android you can do it like this:

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://your.link.com"));
    yourActivity.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

So you'd want to call that block of code in the onClickListeners of whatever buttons you want to link to something.

Comment: To be more precise, I want that when an activity opens, There should be three hyperlinks. If qoura hyperlink is clicked, user will be redirected to my quora profile. If linked in hyperlink is clicked, user will be redirected to my linked in profile. If gmail id is clicked, user will be redirected to his gmail.. with my gmail ID in send section of compose mail.

Comment: Then you would want to add three buttons to you new activity and in each of those buttons onClickListeners onClick methods add the code that i wrote above but replace `"https://your.link.com"` with the appropriate link for that button and replace `yourActivity` with whatever your activity is (if your calling it from the activity you can just remove the `yourActivity.`). For the gmail button you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333119/android-opening-the-email-application) to open the mail

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is that in the activity you are navigating to, you provide three Textviews with the full links to the respective accounts and in each of those Textviews, you set the property 'android:autoLink="web" '. Those views will open the links to your accounts when clicked.

Comment: the link should be provided in 'WEB' ??  'android:autoLink="web" ... here I have to replace 'web' with the link?

Comment: it throws error if i provide the link at the place of 'WEB'.  error- 'failed linking file resources'